# How did the Legion of the Superheroes' real-world leadership election (involving the comic's readers) work in practice?

Tags: dc, legion-of-superheroes

I remember reading a Legion of the Superheroes comic many years ago.  (I think it was *Superboy and the Legion of the Superheroes* no. 251, from 1979, at the end of which Matter-Eater Lad eats the Miracle Machine and goes insane.)  In the letter column, there was several paragraphs of discussion about an apparent election for the leader of the Legion*—but the election occurred both in universe and out, with the fans apparently having voted for the next leader.  I am wondering how the fan voting was actually handled; I presume it must have been by mail, but I know nothing else about what happened, except for the outcome.

The issue listed how many votes each candidate had gotten, with Superboy having won the actual balloting fairly easily.  (I think he got about 80 votes, out of several hundred total.**)  Lots of sources online state that Superboy was not elected leader because he was only a part-time member, having to travel through time to participate in the Legion.  However, this seems to have been only the in-universe story of what happened.  As I recall, the second-highest vote total went to Brainiac 5, but the editors brushed aside with little explanation—although Brainiac 5's loss was portrayed as a contributing factor to the insanity he was suffering from in issue no. 251.  Moving down the list, the next candidate was the relative newcomer Wildfire, who became the leader of the Legion.

All that I picked up and remember from the issue, but I have always been curious about how fan election played out in real life.

*Invisible Kid, the longtime leader of the Legion, had been killed off in 1974, probably to introduce more dynamism to the leader's role

**The whole election appears to have been an extremely small time and quirky affair.  The editors noted that the sixth- or seventh-highest (with about 30 votes) vote-getter had been a character who had actually not even appeared in the comic book at the time of the election.

Comment: The mechanics of the procedure are unknown to me.  Too bad I've lost touch with a friend-of-a-friend from the 1980's, because he could supply some insight.  As a nerd prank of sorts, he took it upon himself to organize a write-in campaign for Polar Boy.  I missed the campaign, but I don't know how, since he apparently went at it with a zeal that would make real-life election managers envious.  And, in 1987, Polar Boy was leader of the Legion.  I personally doubt the writing/editing staff of the comic took the mail-in count as binding.  Probably used it to inspire story ideas.